# gatsby compression doesn't work in live server, only on local

Tags: amazon-s3, compression, gatsby, static-site, brotli

I am using the brotli plugin for compressing my bundles in gatsby: https://github.com/ovhemert/gatsby-plugin-brotli

the plugin is configured as follows:

```
{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-brotli",
      options: {
        extensions: ["css", "html", "js", "svg", "ttf"],
      },
    },
}
```

For some reason, it seems to work only when I "gatsby serve" it on my local machine (localhost:9000), but uploading it to a bucket on S3, shows no compressions what so ever:

local deployment:
[image: local compression]

s3 deployment:
[image: prod compression]

Nothing works, no matter what I've tried.
for uploading to S3, I've been using the gatsby-plugin-s3 package:
https://github.com/jariz/gatsby-plugin-s3

Any idea?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I checked the bucket to make sure that it contains the compressed files and it does, but also the decompressed files:
[image: s3 bucket]

So I guess I need to refine my questions, but not sure how... not sure what caused this issue

Comment: According to the docs, it should be `js.br` as well as in local development, isn't?

Comment: it won't show any way in the devtool, since it's being served after decompression, but checking the actual type in the headers show that local is served as gzip, and s3 served as a normal file (edited original post(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending quite some time on this issue, I finally found the answer in AWS docs.
I'm using CloudFront to serve the site, but since this site is a demo site for testing purposes, I didn't purchase an HTTPS Cert for it.
According to AWS Docs, CF doesn't serve compressed content over HTTP, ONLY on HTTPS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

Purchasing and installing a certificate SOLVED this problem for me.